# How to install Microsoft CRM modules on Linux PowerShell?

Tags: linux, powershell, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, powershell-4.0

I've installed PowerShell on Linux operating system. My task is to do work with Microsoft CRM by using Linux Powershell commands. But Microsoft CRM commands are not working on Linux PowerShell. For example: 
1) Install-Module Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell -Scope CurrentUser.
2)Update-Module Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell -Force.
3) Set-ExecutionPolicy –ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned –Scope CurrentUser. Above commands are not working on Linux PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft CRM isn't supported on Linux in any way, where is your CRM server located ? You may try using a web browser for the online version thought.

Comment: Currently I using web browser only & server in on premises. And also I've used my local windows machine, by using powershell commands to import and export soluton into CRM server. CRM powershell commands are working fine on windows machine. Now I want to run CRM powershell commands on linux powershell..Is it possible?

Comment: No, CRM module is not compatible on Linux. But I guess could remote PS into your Windows machine from Linux and give it commands from there.